# Rails 3 after_initialize to create a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to use after_initialize in Rails 3 to build someone's first post automatically. I've got default values set up in the model but what I'm hoping is that once the User is created, that it builds their first Post. So instead of just default_values, they'll have a Post entry with ID of 1.

Model:

```
class Etho < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :word_one, :word_two, :word_three, :word_four, :tagline
after_initialize :default_values

private
 def default_values
  self.word_one   ||= "Adventagious"
  self.word_two   ||= "Funny"
  self.word_three ||= "Multidisciplined"
  self.tagline    ||= "Shares the same visions as JFK. Wants to see the world fortune in prosperity."
 end

end
```

Comment: You want a dummy post created when a `User` is first created? Using default values like this is not the way. Instead create the post in a `UserObserver` with whatever values you desire for the dummy post.

Comment: Agree with Zabba, this should be done in response to a user creation not an etho creation. Put it in an observer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html (or less correctly the user controller create method)

Comment: Do you guys have an example of what that might look like using ActiveRecord Observer. The examples are kind of challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot I could build inside the controller. So now I have a :default in the migration and then on User create method I do a build.

Inside the migration:

```
add_column :ethos, :tagline, :text, :default => 'Shares a birthday with JFK. Believes in prosperty amongst humans.'
```

Inside the create method on User

```
ethos = @user.ethos.build
```

Thanks for the help Chris Duesing!

Answer (score 0):

> Just use callback methods "after_save"

class Etho < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :word_one, :word_two, :word_three, :word_four, :tagline
after_save :default_values

```
private
 def default_values
  self.word_one   ||= "Adventagious"
  self.word_two   ||= "Funny"
  self.word_three ||= "Multidisciplined"
  self.tagline    ||= "Shares the same visions as JFK. Wants to see the world fortune in prosperity."
 end

end
```